# How to find element by attribute value?

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I want to find the `<issue>` where `id = 6`. How do I do it? I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
<issues>
<issue>
  <id>7</id>
  <project id="1" name="testProject"/>      
  <author id="1" name="testAuthor"/>     
  <subject>subject</subject>
  <start_date>2015-08-24</start_date>      
</issue>
<issue>
  <id>6</id>
  <project id="2" name="testProject2"/>      
  <author id="2" name="testAuthor2"/>     
  <subject>subject2</subject>
  <start_date>2015-08-24</start_date>    
</issue>
</issues>
```

My XPath expression attempts are:

```
doc.xpath("//id[contains(text(), '6']")
```

and

```
doc.xpath("//issue[@id=6]")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the following XPath expression to get the `issue` element having a child element where `id` equals `6`:

```
//issue[id=6]
```

`id` is a child element, not an attribute so you don't use `@id` for this task.

Comment: @yak_ilnur you're welcome. Don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer since it actually *answered* your question